# Calculating the number of events based on weight and probability

Tags: probability

I'm trying to solve an analysis problem on a game I'm playing. In this game there is one actor casting spells repeatedly with no downtime, only one spell may be cast at a time.

I have the following result from 5 minutes of casting (300 seconds)

```
Spell   NumberOfCasts   PercentageOfCasts       CastsPerMinute  CastTime
S1      24              14.29%                  4.8             2.5
S2      78              46.43%                  15.6            1.5
S3      48              28.57%                  9.6             2
S4      18              10.71%                  3.6             1.5
```

Knowing how many casts in that 300 second window makes it very easy to get the % of casts and thus CastsPerMinute.

My problem is I now want to work backwards using only the **Spell, PercentageOfCasts and CastTime** columns, how can I extrapolate from that the CastsPerMinute?

```
Spell   PercentageOfCasts       CastTime
S1      14.29%                  2.5
S2      46.43%                  1.5
S3      28.57%                  2
S4      10.71%                  1.5
```

*Edit: added example data and a clearer description of the problem*

---

*My grasp of probability and statistics is not fantastic, so if answers could be kept relatively simple (if at all possible) that would be great. My end goal is to populate whatever formula or method is required to get the result into a spreadsheet so I can adjust the % values & cast times as needed and see instant results.*

Comment: Well, the average repartition of the number of spells over one minute is the same as the repartition over an hour. Now if you want numbers and not just repartition, we need some more information : are spells casted continuously over the hour ? Can multiple spells be cast at the same time ?

Comment: Is there any downtime, or is some spell always being casted?

Comment: @justt There is continuously only one spell being cast at once - there is no downtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ be the total number of spells cast in one minute.
Then $$60 = x \times .15 \times 2.5 +  x \times .51 \times 1.5 + x \times .21 \times 2   +x \times .13 \times 1.5 \\= x \times ( .15 \times 2.5 +   .51 \times 1.5 +  .21 \times 2  + .13 \times 1.5) \\ = x \times 1.755$$

You get $60 = x \times 1.755$. so $x = \frac {60} {1.755}$.

Now you can multiply back by your repartition percentages to get the average number for each spell.

Comment: I am unable to work backwards using the method you described above using my example data I edited in (unfortunately as you were writing out your answer). I get $y = \frac 1 {1.7857}$ which is 0.56. $0.56 \times .1429 = 0.2551$. I then need to multiply that by 0.0531 to get my original 4.8 casts per minute. This same method works for all of the spell breakdowns, I'm just not sure where the 0.0531 comes from.

Comment: Oooh, sorry, cast time is in seconds... I will edit

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're very welcome !